# List shared between multiple classes

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say I have List of type Invoice and I want to share it between multiple classes. Following single responsibility principle I have to create three separate classes to apply my business logic (I need to use three methods on this `List`). Holding instance in `Main` function and sharing it as a method parameter doesn't seem as a great idea. My `Main` method started to grow really fast and `Invoice` class is just one of my "domain model classes". Is there any solution to keep those things separated from `Main` method? How do you guys handle with this?

```
public class Invoice
{
    //Model
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class A
{
    public List<Invoice> DoAStuff()
    {
        //extract invoices from xlsx file
        return invoices;
    }
}

public class B
{
    public List<Invoice> DoBStuff(List<Invoice> invoices)
    {
        //Do some operations and update list
        return invoices;
    }
}

public class C
{
    public List<Invoice> DoCStuff(List<Invoice> invoices)
    {
        //Do some operations and update list
        return invoices;
    }
}

public class D
{
    public void DoDStuff(List<Invoice> invoices)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to make 3 different classes for 3 different methods, what reason? It's not SRP

Comment: Single responsibility doesn't mean a single public method, but a logical thing, like 'invoice processing' that includes A, B and C, but not unrelated things like user management.

Comment: It`s probably good idea to separate all real logic into Business Logic project, and main method  would just use it. BL should handle the data processing, SRP meaning not mix business logic and main method ... if put it bluntly (but very inaccurate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that you have to decide what responsibilities your `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` classes have, if they do completely different things where they need to be split or if they represent the same concept and you should merge them into one.

To your problem regarding sharing the same `List` between all those classes, there can be many approaches like a `static` class containing the list (which sends you to a Singleton design pattern) or just a static list within those classes, but there is another approach that I like most. You can inject the same `List` into the constructor of these classes, and even have them inheriting the same base class.

Here is a sample:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    protected List<Invoice> Invoices;

    public Base(List<Invoice> invoices)
    {
        Invoices = invoices;
    }
}


public class A : Base
{
    public List<Invoice> DoAStuff()
    {
        //extract invoices from xlsx file
        return invoices;
    }

    public A(List<Invoice> invoices) : base(invoices)
    {
    }
}


public class B : Base
{
    public List<Invoice> DoBStuff()
    {
        //Do some operations and update list
        return invoices;
    }

    public B(List<Invoice> invoices) : base(invoices)
    {
    }
}


public class C : Base
{
    public List<Invoice> DoCStuff()
    {
        //Do some operations and update list
        return invoices;
    }

    public C(List<Invoice> invoices) : base(invoices)
    {
    }
}

public class D : Base
{
    public void DoDStuff()
    {
        //Do Something
    }

    public D(List<Invoice> invoices) : base(invoices)
    {
    }
}
```

And in Main you will call them like this:

```
var invoices = new List<Invoice>();
A a = new A(invoices);
B b = new B(invoices);
C c = new C(invoices);
D d = new D(invoices);
```

You can see that you have access to the same list in all of the classes so now you don't need to send it as parameter to them.

On the other way, I would never place more logic in the entry point of the application other than composing its classes and calling a *Run* method that will take care of the rest of the application logic where it can be unit tested.